# Can you use PREPARE statement or plpgsql function to make first query on new connection fast?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, prepared-statement

Currently, I am standing up an RShiny (web) application that queries data from an AWS RDS PostgresSQL database (PostgresSQL 12) which is pushed forward to my application. When a new user logs into the website, they establish a new connection to our database (important).  I have spent a lot of time optimizing our database structure underneath the website to improve query performance ranging from indexing, reading and optimizing query plans, re-organizing table structures etc.. Unfortunately, I am not achieving the success I need. What I have found is when a query is performed, it is often slow because there is no cached information about the optimal plan. So, when the query is run the first time the data retrieval is slow. However, the second time it is **much quicker** / runs as I have optimized it.

Recently, I have been exploring using `PREPARE` statements with much better success. However, I am running into issues where:

1. The cached `PREPARE` statement is not accessible to another user
2. The cached `PREPARE` statement doesn't persist over multiple connections

My understanding is `PREPARE` statements only exist over the lifetime of the connection, so these findings aren't surprising, but leave me back at my original problem. I could have a series of `PREPARE` statements executed when the user logs in for the first time on the website such that these are available, but that doesn't seem sustainable to me.

Is there a way to have query plans (ideally a `PREPARE` statement of `plpgsql` function) cached over any connection such that the first time a user logs into the website and queries data using the optimized plan on the first attempt? I keep running into this issue where the first query on a new connection is always (frustratingly) slow.

Second, from a higher level is there a better approach here to optimizing website querying performance where the data sits on top of a PostgresSQL database?

**EDIT / UPDATE**
This is the current performance I am receiving between the first and second run. First, using a `plpgsql` function:

```
Planning Time: 0.084 ms
Execution Time: 1411.143 ms
                                                                                                                     Run 2: QUERY PLAN
Planning Time: 0.028 ms
Execution Time: 116.966 ms
```

When I use a `PREPARE` statement:

```
Run 1: QUERY PLAN
Planning Time: 26.579 ms
Execution Time: 232.347 ms
                                                                                                                     Run 2: QUERY PLAN
Planning Time: 16.594 ms
Execution Time: 77.716 ms
```

The difference between the two approach is likely due to some of the tables already being in memory as J.D. mentioned, which can be extended to the behavior between the 1st and 2nd query run.

Ideally, this is run at the high end speed I am seeing on the 2nd runs < 100ms in total time between execution and planning.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™ to me. Preparing a SQL statement simply compiles it, which takes negligible time, compared to how long it takes to actually _execute_ the compiled plan. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions).

Comment: I would bet my money it's not the cached execution plan that's making a significant difference in overall runtime on the second run, rather it may be something like the data pages of your larger tables being in Memory already. How big of a difference is the runtime from first run to second run?

Comment: Please quantify how slow it currently is and how fast you want it to be.

Comment: I updated the post with more details on runtime, thanks for the responses!

Comment: As Laurenz already told you, `PREPARE` only affects the planning time, not the execution time, which is your main concern. To try and explain the difference in execution time, we would need more than the superficial details you provided. Provide information as instructed here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info, and also the exact sequence of events that produced the disclosed times.

Comment: While your planning got a little bit faster, your execution time got a lot faster between 1st and 2nd execution.  I am guessing that each time you connect, you are querying a different set of data (same query maybe, but with different parameters) so it is about the caching of the data itself, not the plan.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cache execution plans across database connections in PostgreSQL.

However, I doubt that planning time is really your problem. Convince yourself by running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) /* your query */` and looking for the `Planning Time`. That will not vary much. It is on this planning time that you can save by using prepared statements.

The more likely cause for varying execution times is caching. It makes a lot of different if you read 1000 8kB pages from disk or find them cached in RAM. To diagnose that, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) /* your query */` and look at the buffer count. The higher it is, the more sensitive to caching effects your performance will be. Try to tune your queries to have a smaller footprint or get more RAM to cache the database.

Comment: Thanks! When I do that, I see this between the first and second query `Buffers: shared hit=18480 read=531 written=109` and then on the second run `Buffers: shared hit=18959`. Are there general strategies to tune my queries with rest buffers?

Comment: 19000 8kB blocks leaves plenty of room for caching effects - that is 150 MB or so. Anyway, the planning time is comparatively small (seems to be a complicated query).